# function is setting all instead of each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function that sets the width of a bar based on an argument.

And I call the function on .each with jQuery.

The console logs the statement correctly, showing me it seems to work.  However, the style seems to be overridden by the last value found.

Here is the function:

```
function barGraph(innerWidth, barWidth) {
    innerWidth = parseInt(innerWidth) * .01 || .50;
    barWidth = parseInt(barWidth) || 267;

   // find percentage of total width
   var innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   $innerBar.css('width', innerWidth + 'px');

   console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
}
```

then i call the function on each with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   $innerBar.each(function(index) {
       var newWidth = $(this).attr("data-bar-width");
       barGraph(newWidth, 267);
   });
});
```

the console log shows 10 times, with all appropriate widths.  However, the style for all is the same as the last width.

Can someone help explain how I get the function to set the width of the currently selected div?

Thanks so much in advance,

Adam.

Comment: Those were all perfect answers.  And all lead me to an easy fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   // going to call the barGraph function on each matching element
   // so far, so good
   $innerBar.each(function(index) {
       var newWidth = $(this).attr("data-bar-width");
       barGraph(newWidth, 267);
   });
});
```

Then in `barGraph`

```
function barGraph(innerWidth, barWidth) {
    innerWidth = parseInt(innerWidth) * .01 || .50;
    barWidth = parseInt(barWidth) || 267;

   // find percentage of total width
   var innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

   // getting all the matching elements (again)
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   // setting the width of each matched element to 
   // the innerwidth calculated in this barGraph call.
   $innerBar.css('width', innerWidth + 'px');

   console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
}
```

So, the `barGraph` function is run as many times as there are matched elements in `$('.slider-box div')`, but each run sets the width of all matched elements. In effect, the last run will set the width of all matched elements to whatever the `innerWidth` is calculated to be on the last run. Is that what you want to happen?

What is more likely is perhaps something like this

```
$(function() {
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   // going to call the barGraph function on each matching element
   // so far, so good
   $innerBar.each(function(index) {
       var bar = $(this),
           newWidth = bar.attr("data-bar-width");
       barGraph(bar, newWidth, 267);
   });

   function barGraph(bar, innerWidth, barWidth) {
       innerWidth = parseInt(innerWidth, 10) * .01 || .50;
       barWidth = parseInt(barWidth, 10) || 267;

       innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

       bar.css('width', innerWidth + 'px');

       console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
   }

});
```

If the barGraph function is not used outside of the `each` call, then I might be inclined to move the function body inside of the anonymous function passed to `each` or modify barGraph function to be the function passed to each i.e.

```
$(function() {

   $('.slider-box div').each(barGraph);

   function barGraph(index, element) {
       var bar = $(this),
           newWidth = bar.attr("data-bar-width");

       newWidth = parseInt(newWidth , 10) * .01 || .50;
       newWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * 267);

       bar.css('width', newWidth + 'px');

       console.log("Width should be: " + newWidth + 'px');
   }

});
```

Comment: Thank you Russ!  Your explanation was great.  Thank you for taking the time to show me so cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in here, have a look at your barGraph function:

```
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div'); //here you choose all divs inside .slider-box

   $innerBar.css('width', innerWidth + 'px'); //and set the width for all of them
```

change the barGraph function:

```
function barGraph(innerWidth, barWidth) {
    innerWidth = parseInt(innerWidth) * .01 || .50;
    barWidth = parseInt(barWidth) || 267;

   // find percentage of total width
   var innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');
   $innerBar.each(function(index){
 $(this).css('width', innerWidth + 'px');
});

   console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashkan, I had tried using $(this) however, it appears i need to add .call to the end of the function and pass (this) inside the arguments to get it to work:  Like so:  barGraph.call(this, newWidth, 267);

Comment: well i edited my answer edit your function. it should solve the problem

Comment: The problem here is that `this` inside of the barGraph function does not reference the `this` in each `each()` anonymous function iteration. You would either need to pass a function context to `barGraph` using `call()` or `apply()` or pass `this` from the anonymous function as an argument to `barGraph`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ashkan.  But Russ is absolutely right.  using call, definitely solved the problem.  However, for ease of reuse, I passed an extra element in the function to refer to this.

Answer (score 1):

this may happen bacause on last `barGraph()` call you set all `$('.slider-box div');`
 with last value you read into the `each()`

what if you try something like this

```
function barGraph(el, innerWidth, barWidth) {
   ...

   el.css('width', innerWidth + 'px');
   console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   $innerBar.each(function(index, el) {
       var newWidth = $(el).attr("data-bar-width");
       barGraph($(el), newWidth, 267);
   });
});
```

in this approach I passed a jQuery reference to each element, to the `barGraph()` function. It's also less expensive than before, since you always create a jQuery reference to a div collection.

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio, I think this is a good alternative of using .call.

Answer (score 1):

In your `barGraph` function you select all instances of `.slider-box div` and set the width. You only want to set the one you are currently working with.

```
function barGraph($bar, innerWidth, barWidth) {
    innerWidth = parseInt(innerWidth) * .01 || .50;
    barWidth = parseInt(barWidth) || 267;

   // find percentage of total width
   var innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

   $bar.css('width', innerWidth + 'px');

   console.log("Width should be: " + innerWidth + 'px');
}
```

by passing the bar into barGraph during the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

   $innerBar.each(function(index) {
       var $bar = $(this)
         , newWidth = $bar.attr("data-bar-width");
       barGraph($bar, newWidth, 267);
   });
});
```

You may also want to move the selection of the width into the `barGraph` function to keep things clean.

Comment: Thank you Phil.  That's also a good point.  I'd rather not put the function inside the loop for ease of reuse.  But this solution is definitely a valid one.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Like most of jQuery's functions, [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) works on **collections** as well as on single elements. Since `$('.slider-box div')` returns a collection, the CSS rule will be applied to **all** of the divs on every iteration of the `each` loop. So for 10 divs, `barGraph` will be called 10 × 10 = 100 times. And because the divs stay in the same order, the `newWidth` of the last div will be applied to all of the divs.

To apply the `newWidth` only to the current element in the `each` loop, you could keep all your logic inside that function:

```
var $innerBar = $('.slider-box div');

$('.slider-box div').each(function(index, element) {
    var $this      = $(this);
    var innerWidth = ($this.attr("data-bar-width") / 10) || 0.5;
    var barWidth   = 267;

    innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

    $this.css('width', innerWidth); // Note: no need to append 'px'; jQuery
});
```

This works pretty well as long as the logic is simple (a couple of lines at most) and you don't need to use it elsewhere. But when your code gets a bit more complex, you might want to brake it out into a separate function. Since you had already done this, let's look at some other solutions.

Two common solutions:

- Eiter: pass the current element as a parameter of the function;
- or: make it into a jQuery plugin.

The first is pretty simple:

```
function barGraph(element, innerWidth, barWidth) {
    var $this = $(element);
    // et cetera
}

// Call like this:
$('.slider-box div').each(function(index) {
    var newWidth = $(this).attr("data-bar-width");
    barGraph(this, newWidth, 267);
});
```

Like I said: simple. But it's not very neat, is it? The second solution is a bit more elegant:

```
$.fn.barGraph = function(barWidth) {
    var $this      = this; // `this` is already a jQuery object
    var innerWidth = ($this.attr("data-bar-width") / 10) || 0.5;
    barWidth       = barWidth || 267;

    innerWidth = Math.floor(innerWidth * barWidth);

    $this.css('width', innerWidth);
};

// Use like this:
$('.slider-box div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).barGraph(267);
});
```

And that's how easy it is to write your own jQuery plugin! Of course, it can use a little work, like a more descriptive name and support for [chainability](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability).

Comment: ooh.  this is a good thought.  thanks PPvG!  I might just port it to a tiny plugin.

Comment: @Adam: Slight update to show you could make `barWidth` an argument for the `barGraph()` "plugin[ette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive#French)".

Comment: Yup.  love it.  i already started on one today.  i'll post when i'm finished.  thanks again.